# How to split the terminal when running tasks in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code you can now split the integrated terminal in half. I am using  VSCode's tasks feature as well to run two tasks always at the same time. How can I make it so when I run a task it will automatically split the current terminal, using the new one for the task?

Basically I'm wanting to open VSCode, it should auto open the integrated terminal like normal, and then I can run my two tasks which should end me with a terminal split into three like so:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| default terminal   | Task 1       | Task 2         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT (SOLVED):**
VSCode has been updated to allow this now :D
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_task-output-support-split-terminals

> You can now configure tasks to show output in a split terminal panel instead of creating a new one. A task configuration can use the **group** attribute in the **presentation** section to define where the task's output should be shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating your task make sure to have the `presentation.reveal` option set to `always` and `presentation.panel` option set to `new`. That way the output is **always** revealed and a **new** terminal is created on every task run

Example:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./scripts/test.sh",
            "windows": {
                "command": ".\\scripts\\test.cmd"
            },
            "group": "test",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

More info at: [Tasks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior)

**EDIT**: Since you want new tasks into split terminals, maybe this info helps. I don't think it is possible to do it: [Launch task directly into split terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47265)

Comment: I don't see how this helps me run new tasks in a split terminal view. This just makes them display in new terminals, but they don't split to show both at the same time.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Check the feature request I added in the answer, found in their GitHub.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the feature request link though! Bounty awarded for edit.

Answer (score 7):

The following should work:

```
{
    "type": "process",
    "label": "terminal",
    "command": "/bin/bash",  // <-- your shell here
    "args": [
        "-l"  // login shell for bash
    ],
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": false,  // silence "Executing task ..."
        "focus": true,
        "group": "sxs",  // some arbitrary name for the group
        "panel": "dedicated"
    },
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
}
```

Here, I'm auto-launching (and setting the focus on) the terminal when the folder is opened in vscode -- and further tasks that share the same `presentation.group` gets placed in split terminals when they're run (with new vs. reused splits depending on their `presentation.panel`)

Note: For this example, you may or may not need the `-l` option depending on your settings for `terminal.integrated.shell*`, `terminal.integrated.automationShell*` and `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` -- [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70248) issue has some discussion on what is involved in setting up the shell environment.

Comment: This set me on the correct path. I used the presentation.panel = "shared" instead. That worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Direct support for this was added in the [January 2019](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_task-output-support-split-terminals) update.

Setting the same name for the `presentation.group` property of each task will cause the tasks to appear in split terminals. From the VS Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior):

> **group:** Controls whether the task is executed in a specific terminal group using split panes. Tasks in the same group (specified by a string value) will use split terminals to present instead of a new terminal panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tmux to split your terminal not just inside vscode, but in all your terminals.

### MacOS Installation

The easiest way to get started with tmux on a Mac is to use the Homebrew package manager.

1. If you don’t have Homebrew installed yet, open either Terminal or iTerm and paste the below command:

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. Once Homebrew is installed, you can use brew to install tmux:

brew install tmux

3. Confirm that it installed by checking the version (note the uppercase V):

tmux -V

### Ubuntu / Debian Linux Installation

Installation for Ubuntu is similar to Mac, except that we will be using the apt-get package manager that comes pre-installed. Note that we will have to run apt-get as sudo. This is because a user account won’t have enough privileges to install tmux, so sudo will allow us to install it as superuser.

1. Update apt-get to make sure we are on the latest and greatest:

sudo apt-get update

2. Install tmux:

sudo apt-get install tmux

3. Confirm that it installed by checking the version:

tmux -V

### After installing

Use the `tmux` command to start a new session, then press ctrl/cmd + b and % for vertical split or " for horizontal split.

### References

[How to install tmux](https://hackernoon.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-tmux-8d784c404340)

[Tmux cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058)

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of tmux but would prefer to keep things simple by utilizing built in vscode features.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply split the 
terminal via shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>5</kbd>

> Note: Tested on version 1.36.1 or greater

Comment: "How can I make it so when I run a task it will **automatically** split the current terminal"